# distribution of $\|P_VX\|^2$ with orthogonal projection $P$ onto $V$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We've had the following question discussed today but without any result:

Let $X_1,\dots,X_d$ be random variables, iid and $X_n\sim N(\mu_n,1)$.

How can we describe the distribution of $\|P_VX\|^2$ with $X=(X_1,\dots,X_d)$, $V\subset \mathbb R^d$ and an orthogonal projection $P$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** use the fact that 
$$
P_V(I - P_V) = 0
$$
and the [Cochran theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran's_theorem).

Comment: That is the standard one, at least. This is a very classical approach presented in many books of statistics.

Comment: My problem is to find the $q_i$'s, how do you get them?

Comment: The version of the theorem in the link is not the most clear I have seen, I'm sorry for that. I'll give a working version here: if $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ and if you can find orthogonal projectors $p_i$ whose sum is $id$ and such as $i\neq j\implies p_i\circ p_j = 0$, then the variables $p_i X$ are independant, with marginals $N(p_i\mu, p_i \Sigma p_i)$